# Outlook 2010 and href to open folders/messages

Tags: c#-4.0, exchangewebservices, vb.net-2010, outlook-2010

Back in the day, Outlook 2003, I wrote an app that would go out and check a users mailbox for all messages that were over a certain size, then send them a HTML report with links to those messages.  They could click the link and it would take them directly to the message.

Now, new company and several versions of Outlook later, Outlook 2010 now, I am attempting to do the same.  Only problem is, everything I have read states that the HREF for Outlook:inbox (or whatever) is no longer supported.

It seems odd to me that such a handy feature would be removed.  Is there a workaround for this?

I have searched and searched the web but to no avail.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Geo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MAPIFolder.FolderPath` returns path to current folder.